# How to make read more text using hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 5 texts and 2 of them are hidden. In js code below I can see these 2 texts using `click`, but I need to use `hover` effect. How can I solve that?

js:

```
$('p#string').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('span.span_icon').toggleClass('active');
});

$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).parent().height() >= 50) {
        $(this).parent().animate({
            height: 25 + 'px'
        });
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active-animated').css('zIndex','1');
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().css('zIndex','1');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().animate({
            height: 100 + '%'
        });
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().css('zIndex','9999');
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active-animated');
    }
});
```

html:

```
<div class="bottom">
<a href="">First Text</a>
<a href="">Second Text</a>
<a href="">Third Text</a><br>
<a href="">Fourth Text</a>
<a href="">Fifth Text</a>    
<p id="string" class="btn"><span class="span_icon">+</span></p>
</div>
```

I need to make hover effect, I mean when I hover on my block of texts I need to see another 2 hidden texts. Help me in this question.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, just change `click` to `mouseover` to fire the event when a user hovers over the bound element.

Comment: why two click `$('p#string') and $('.btn')` both targeted element are same

Comment: @AndroidNoobie Thank you! but how can I make to all block, not only to icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always just do this with **PURE CSS** if that works for you.

```css
.bottom {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}

.bottom a {
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom:25px;
}

#btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

#btn:hover+.bottom {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <p id="btn">+</p>
  <div class="bottom">
    <a href="">First Text</a>
    <a href="">Second Text</a>
    <a href="">Third Text</a><br>
    <a href="">Fourth Text</a>
    <a href="">Fifth Text</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR Hover on everything

```css
.bottom {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.bottom a {
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#wrap:hover .bottom {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="bottom">
    <a href="">First Text</a>
    <a href="">Second Text</a>
    <a href="">Third Text</a><br>
    <a href="">Fourth Text</a>
    <a href="">Fifth Text</a>
  </div>
  <p id="string" class="btn"><span class="span_icon">+</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I make hover on all block not only to icon?

Comment: What do you mean by `all` block? `.bottom`?

Comment: yes, I need to hover on `.bootom` and could you show it using my `js` code? I tried to change classes but it did not help

Comment: Thank you, it works! and one more question. when I see hidden text, my lower blocks move down. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$('.btn').on('click')` use `$('.btn').on('mouseOver')`

Comment: but if I want to hover on block, not only on icon, then how can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: With $('.bottom').on('mouseOver'). This means that every time you hover on any part of your `bottom` element (including three texts inside) you will see all five of them.

Answer (score 0):

Css selector can be user for hover.Below code well change the "a" tag to yellow background using css selector

```
a:hover { 
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

For hover javascript functions jquery can be used as below

```js
   

 $('.btn').hover(function () {
        if ($(this).parent().height() >= 50) {
            $(this).parent().animate({
                height: 25 + 'px'
            });
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('active-animated').css('zIndex','1');
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().css('zIndex','1');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().animate({
                height: 100 + '%'
            });
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().css('zIndex','9999');
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass('active-animated');
        }
    });
```

```html
   

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="bottom">
    <a href="">First Text</a>
    <a href="">Second Text</a>
    <a href="">Third Text</a><br>
    <a href="">Fourth Text</a>
    <a href="">Fifth Text</a> 
    <br>
    <Button id="string" class="btn"><span class="span_icon">+</span></Button>
    </div>
```

Comment: @AsasSas i haved attached a jquery function to handed hover using javascript. As you have asked :)